# Netsuite PHP toolkit update Sales Order

Tags: php, netsuite

I need to update a custbody field in my sales order:

The field are a dropdown, and a checkbox. How do I send the "check" value to the checkbox field? The result returns "Success" but the field is never updated from it's existing value. Here is my code.

```
$customStringFieldList = new StringCustomFieldRef();
$customStringFieldList->internalId = "custbody_order_status";
$customStringFieldList->value = "Cancelled";

$customSelectFieldList = new SelectCustomFieldRef();
$customSelectFieldList->value = new ListOrRecordRef();
$customSelectFieldList->value->internalId = 49;
$customSelectFieldList->internalId = 'custbody_shipping_confirmed';
//send true?

$basicCustomRecord = new SalesOrder();
$basicCustomRecord->internalId = "114467"; // internal id of the custom record you want to update
$basicCustomRecord->recType = new RecordRef();
$basicCustomRecord->customFieldList = new CustomFieldList();
$basicCustomRecord->customFieldList->customField = array($customStringFieldList, $customSelectFieldList);

$updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
$updateRequest->record = $basicCustomRecord;

$updateResponse = $service->update($updateRequest);

var_dump($updateResponse);
if (!$updateResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "UPDATE ERROR";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "UPDATE SUCCESS, id " . $updateResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it for anyone who has to suffer this problem in the future:

```
 $si = 'internal value of the option you can find this in custom settings';

 $customSelectFieldList = new SelectCustomFieldRef();
 $customSelectFieldList->value = new ListOrRecordRef();
 $customSelectFieldList->value->internalId = $s_id;
 $customSelectFieldList->scriptId = 'custbody_order_status';


  $aBooleanField = new BooleanCustomFieldRef();
  $aBooleanField->value = true;
  $aBooleanField->scriptId = 'custbody_move_confirmed';



            $SalesOrderId = 437127;
            $SalesOrderRecord = new SalesOrder();
            $SalesOrderRecord->internalId  = $SalesOrderId;


            $SalesOrderRecord->customFieldList = new CustomFieldList();
            $SalesOrderRecord->customFieldList->customField = array($customSelectFieldList,$aBooleanField);

            $updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
            $updateRequest->record = $SalesOrderRecord;

            $updateResponse = $service->update($updateRequest);


            if (!$updateResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
                echo "UPDATE ERROR";
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "UPDATE SUCCESS, id " . $updateResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing it; but, I don't see where you are setting a checked or unchecked value.

That said, in SuiteScript 1.0, you would use 'T' or 'F' to check and uncheck a checkbox, as the value of the field.

In 2.0, I usually able to use true or false (boolean values, not strings).